# Delete all folders except which are mapped in symlinks

Tags: find, symlink, rm, delete

I need to delete folders that are not in use. There are a few symlinks which points to this folder. My requirement here is in 3 step.

1) Get all the available folders at top level which are not empty

2) Get all folders not empty and symlink pointing to them.

3) Delete those folders not in symlink. So this is basically step 1- step 2.

Example:

Folder A, B ,C
Within A, B, C you will have multiple folders like x,y,z.

`A(x1, y1,z1), B (x2, 2, z2), C(x3, y3, z3)`

Symlink folder 1 ( Similarly one more symlinks 2 exist)

```
a-->A/x1
b-->C/z3
c-->B/y2
```

I need to get all non empty first and then those these symlinks points. At last need to delete folders (non empty) and not pointing in any symlinks.

I had seen few post but they have either one specific or one specific type of folders in exclude. Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the fact that the `rmdir` command will only remove a directory that is empty.

First use `find <folder structure root> -type d` to gather a list of all folders (empty or not). Save it into a temporary file.

Then collect a list of all symlink destinations. Use this list to filter out any matching folders in the first list, producing a third list: all folders that are not symlink targets.

Then run `rmdir` on each folder in the third list, intentionally ignoring any "directory is not empty" errors. Only empty folders will actually get deleted.